# How can you bubble up errors so they can be caught in the same try/catch block?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I've got an object with functions that throw errors,

```
myObj = {
  ini:function(){
    this.f();
  },
  f:function(){
   throw new Error();
  } 
};
```

but I only want to catch the exceptions where the object is created

```
try{
  var o = new myObj();
}catch(err){
  alert("error!");
}
```

it looks like i have to have try/catch blocks everywhere =/ to capture the error event in different function scopes

```
try{
    myObj = {
      ini:function(){
        try{
          this.f();
        }catch(err){
         alert("f threw an err");
        }
      },
      f:function(){
       throw new Error();
      } 
    };
}catch(err){
 alert("error happend while crating Obj");
}
```

But I only want to capture from one place =/ How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have your function throw a specific type of object, and then in your catch block check to see `if (err instanceof MyExceptionObj)` and handle appropriately, otherwise re-throw it.

By re-throw I mean:

If the caught exception object isn't one you can handle, you should re-throw it to give any catch blocks further up a chance to handle it.  If none do, the browser will catch it and display a JS error.

```
try {
   if ($.browser.msie) {
      throw new UnsupportedBrowserException();
   }
} catch (ex) {
   if (ex instanceof UnsupportedBrowserException) {
      alert('Your browser isn't supported.');
   } else {
      // We don't know how to handle this exception, throw it back.
      throw ex;
   }
}
```

You probably wouldn't do this in the real world.

Comment: why wouldnt you "do this in the real world" ?

Comment: Hmm, does this mean that try only catches exceptions thrown by called functions, and not the functions they call? I am reading the original question as asking “do I need to catch exceptions on every level?”, and this answer means yes? Rethrowing is nice, but I hoped exceptions would bubble up, which they don't seem to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can only conditionally catch exceptions in JavaScript 1.7 and higher. Refer to the following:

```
try {
  0();
} catch (ex if ex instanceof TypeError) {
  // only catch TypeErrors
}
```

Otherwise, you have to catch all exceptions, do an `instanceof` check, and then rethrow the exceptions if the check returns true.

Answer (score 0):

maybe instead of throwing an error and then catching it, you could just call a function.