# How to know whether the object contains in my Array List of jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my Ajax success function data, I am getting a list of objects. I have one more array list with objects which are of same type. How to write a condition to check if that object contains in my list?

```
//In my Ajax Success function
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
//This is my another array list
var target = [];
target = self.target();                    
//Need to check the condition whether the above "item" is in my above array list
```

I am doing something like this, its not working

```
if (target.indexOf(item) !== -1) {
    //item is not present in the above target array list 
    console.log(item);
} else {
    console.log(item.FullName);
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` will only work if the Object in the Array is the same as your "item" (one Object, referenced in multiple places). If these Objects were created separately, it won't ([JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5ner6ta6/)). In your case, I would use  [`Array.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/some)  with [this method to compare Objects](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1144249/1913729). [JS Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2zhw5Lvp/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [How to determine if object is in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587061/how-to-determine-if-object-is-in-array)

```
function containsObject(obj, list) {
var i;
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].YourId === obj.Id) {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
}
```