# Check if same object exists in an array - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects as follows

```
[{name: "jack", age: 10}, {name: "john", age: 15}]
```

Consider that i have an object

```
{name: "jack", age: 10}
```

Now i need to check if this object exist in the array. If all the properties(name, age) of the object matches, then display an alert on the page.

How to accomplish this using pure javascript?

Comment: accomplish it by checking all the "primitive" properties match - Object.keys/Object.values or Object.entries can help

Comment: The same object literal never exists anywhere else ...

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587061/how-to-determine-if-object-is-in-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if object is in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587061/how-to-determine-if-object-is-in-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

A match will be counted if

- There are equal number of keys
- There is a match for every key/value pair

```js
var arr = [{name: "jack", age: 10}, {name: "john", age: 15}];

var input = {name: "jack", age: 10};

var result = arr.some((o) => Object.entries(input).every(([k,v]) => o[k] === v) && Object.keys(input).length === Object.keys(o).length);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @NinaScholz - Updated

Comment: nearly. you need a check for the key as well (`undefined` is a value or a state).

Comment: @NinaScholz - Need a check for the keys? Can you please explain? Not able to get your point

Comment: if `input` has `foo: undefined` and in array does no object has this key, the value is missing, because for not set properties, the value is `undefined`, which is in this case a state and in the given object for checking, it's a value.

Comment: @NinaScholz - Makes sense. However, I think the length check will negate this case. What do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171747/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-nikhil-aggarwal).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = [{name: "jack", age: 10}, {name: "john", age: 15}];
var input = {name: "jack", age: 10};
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
    if(data[i].name==input.name && data[i].age == input.age)
    {
        alert('matched');
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bad performing method, but it would cover nested object cases with ease. Also this is only suited if ALL key/value pairs must match and that the key/value pairs were defined in the same order.

```js
let c = [{name: "jack", age: 10}, {name: "john", age: 15}],
    s = {name: "jack", age: 10};

console.log(c.filter(e => JSON.stringify(s) === JSON.stringify(e)));
```

Comment: No. This will not work. If the order of keys are different it will fail.

Comment: Yes, only if the objects were declared the same way with the same key order, will add to response.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you don't want to check for index of object inside array object

```js
var obj = [{name: "jack", age: 10}, {name: "john", age: 15}];

var checkObj = {name: "john", age: 15};

if(JSON.stringify(obj).indexOf(JSON.stringify(checkObj)) >= 0){
  console.log("Object Available");
}else{
  console.log("Object Not Available");
}
```