# How can I add an element into an object and how test the existence of a value in a complex object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I am new into JavaScript and I have few questions please. First, I am going through two objects to compute the difference between them. So, I have my loop and bunch of if statement for testing. What I am doing is if I find the element I am looking for, I need to add it to a new object while my object is a key and value. The format is like this: 
`obj={programValue[i] : deviceValue[i]}` I do it like that because I want this format : `obj={'p1': 'app1'}`

This result an error, how can I add an element in my object?

My second question is how can I go through an objects that contains other objects itself and test the existence of a key or a value of another objects that contains objects as well.
Here is an example to explain: 
`var obj1={{'p1':'app1'}, {'p2':'app2'}};`

```
var obj2= {{'p1':'app2'}, {'p1':'app1'}}
```

So I want to test if `app2` from obj1 exists in obj2, if so then test the key too. What I need is that they have some value (app) but different keys (p1 or p2).
I tried many things but didn't fulfill what I need.

Thank you,

Comment: `{{'p1':'app2'}, {'p1':'app1'}}` is not a valid javascript object

Comment: If you are trying to use a dynamic property name during initialization you need to use the correct [syntax for computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) if your environment supports it

Comment: Ok thank you @PatrickEvans , will do that.

Comment: @Dom why? can't we have object of objects?

Comment: Sure you can. But objects are consist of `key: value` pairs. `{{'p1':'app2'}}` is missing the key of the outer object. Maybe you want an array of objects instead? Either way, please ask only one question per question.

Comment: @FelixKling I will recheck my results and maybe I can change it to an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use es6 computed properties

```
var obj={[programValue[i]] : deviceValue[i]}
```

or with es5

```
var obj={};
obj[programValue[i]] = deviceValue[i];
```

Also for 2nd question:

```
Object.entries(obj1).some(([key1, value1])=>Object.entries(obj2).some(([key2, value2])=>key1===key2 && value1===value2))
```

Comment: I am using es5, but when I try that method, it only adds one element. Since I am putting it in a loop so it can iterate and add element into my object. Do you know why is that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For question 1:

The format is like this:  obj={programValue[i] : deviceValue[i]} I do it like that because I want this format : obj={'p1': 'app1'}, This result an error, how can I add an element in my object?

If using ES6, you can do it like this
let obj = {[programValue[i]]:deviceValue[i]};

If programValue[i] returns 'p1' and deviceValue[i] returns 'app1'
then your obj will be {'p1':'app1'}

If you are not using ES6, then you will have to first declare empty object and then set your properties

var obj = {};
obj[[programValue[i]] = deviceValue[i];

For your second question, 
var obj2= {{'p1':'app2'}, {'p1':'app1'}}

That structure wont work. It has to be an array of objects. Then you can iterate through your array or directly access the element using index.

var obj2 =[{'p1':'app1'}, {'p2':'app2'}]

obj2[0].p1 // app1

if you still need an object, then you need a property for each of the object

var obj2 = {one: {'p1':'app1}, two: {'p2':'app2}}

obj2.one.p1 //app1

Answer (score 0):

`var obj2 = {{'p1':'app2'}, {'p1':'app1'}}`  is not a valid syntax. The correct object syntax would be `var obj2 = {'p1':'app2', 'p2':'app1'}`.

To add an element to an object you can do `object2['someUniqueId'] = 'whatever you like'` or `object2.someUniqueId = 'whatever you like'`

I believe you have to turn both `obj1` and `obj2` into an Array: `var obj1 = [{'p1':'app1'}, {'p2':'app2'}];` `var obj2 = [{'p1':'app1'}, {'p2':'app2'}];` and then you could try to check if an object is in your Array `obj2` with this example [How to determine if object is in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587061/how-to-determine-if-object-is-in-array)

Comment: When I try object2.programValue[i] = deviceValue[i]  it doesn't work and says cannot read property '0' undefined coz my i = 0 on that time

Comment: if i = 0 you have to make sure that `object2.programValue[i]` and `deviceValue[i]` are both Arrays. Both have to be constructed as follows `var deviceValue = ["value", "value2"];` and `object2.programValue = []` to get deviceValue[0] wich equals to "value" and placing it into programValue[0]