# filtering an array of objects before using push function in Typescript

Tags: arrays, filter, push, arrayobject

this is a simplified version of what I am trying to achieve.

I have an array of objects and I am mapping to a new array. Now, the possibility is that a new load of data in array form will be added to the previously created array of objects. But before I add the new objects the the exiting array, I need to check if the same data already exists. I tried to use filter below but does not seem to work. Any idea?

```
let arr:IOption[] = [
{key:1,text:"key1"},
{key:2,text:"key2"},
{key:3,text:"key3"},
];

let arr2:IOption[] = [
{key:1,text:"key1"},
{key:2,text:"key2"},
{key:3,text:"key3"},
{key:4,text:"key4"},
];

let newArray:IOption[] = [];
arr.map((item)=>{
newArray.push(item);
});


arr2.map((newItem)=>{
newArray = newArray.filter(s => s.key !== newItem.key);
//newArray = newArray.filter((s) => {return s.key !== 1});

newArray.push(newItem);
});


let output = "";
newArray.forEach((item)=>{
output+=item.key + " "; 
})
document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = output;
```

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587061/how-to-determine-if-object-is-in-array) might help you.

Extract from the post above, but with a small modification: `list[i].key === obj.key`

```
function containsObject(obj, list) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].key === obj.key) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```