# Check for duplicates before adding to javascript array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React function, where I want to add an object to a javascript array. So far I have this

```
 selectAnimalHandler = (animal) =>{
    console.log(animal.id)
    if(this.state.animals.find(ani => ani !== animal )){
    this.setState(prevState =>(
        {selectedAnimals: [...prevState.selectedAnimals, animal]}))
    }
}
```

the logic is to check rather an element already exist in an array, and if it does not exist add it to the array. 
I try to make a condition, rather the element exists in the array or not. 
if it does not exist, nothing happens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if object is in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587061/how-to-determine-if-object-is-in-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement `this.state.animals.find(ani => ani !== animal )` returns a value even if `animal` is in the array.

You should use something like this `!this.state.animals.find(ani => ani === animal )`

Also, keep in mind that `===` or even `==` used on objects is only `true` if you compare two references to the same thing.

Comment: inside a condition?

Comment: @baileyhaldwin I'm not sure what you mean. The equal thing is true inside of conditions,

Comment: The condition returns false everytime

Comment: @baileyhaldwin That is probably because `this.state.animals` contains objects and `animal` is not an object from inside that array.

Comment: @baileyhaldwin You should use something like `!this.state.animals.find(ani => ani.id === animal.id )`

Comment: to add to my state?

Comment: @baileyhaldwin I don't know, I'm not sure what `this.state.animals` or `animals` look like.