# How to find out if an object with particular data-attributes exists in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects containing different server configurations. For example, objects with attributes for URL, Username, Password etc...
I want to prevent the user from entering duplicate server configuration objects in this array of objects. How can I do that?

I am not looking for reference checks using "===". It only checks for the references. I need to compare all the attributes of each object and push only when the configuration does not exist in the array.

```
Array: 
[{
    "url": "test.com",
    "username": "Rishabh",
    "apiKeys": "test",
    "jobName": "testJob"
}, {
    "url": "test2.com",
    "username": "Rishabh2",
    "apiKeys": "test",
    "jobName": "testJob"
}]

Input: 
{
    "url": "test2.com",
    "username": "Rishabh2",
    "apiKeys": "test",
    "jobName": "testJob"
}
```

For the above array and input, the result should be negative (i.e. duplicate entry).

This question, [How to determine if object is in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587061/how-to-determine-if-object-is-in-array), doesn't answer my question. It clearly says that "car1 and car4 contain the same data but are different instances they should be tested as not equal." I want the opposite. If 2 objects contain the same data, they should be considered equal. 
Also, I want to compare the property names as well as values.

Comment: You could use some method in combination with Object.keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case the occurrence/order of keys in your object will always be the same. Then you can use the below snippet which stringifies objects and checks if they are same.

```
var duplicateEntry=false;
existingConfigurationArr.forEach(function(item) {
    if(JSON.stringify(userInputObject) == JSON.stringify(item)){
        duplicateEntry=true;
    }; 
});
alert(duplicateEntry);
```

In case key order of your JSON object are not sure. follow [Sort JavaScript object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467129/sort-javascript-object-by-key) . and utilise this in above code snippet before comparing the object.

Comment: Above solution will fail if order of keys in objects are not same even though all key value pairs matches.

Comment: @AkshayBande I guess you haven't seen the second paragraph or my reply. Where i mentioned the case you are claiming.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use some comparison code, you could leverage schema validation packages. Like `@hapi/joi` (https://github.com/hapijs/joi). The code will look like this

```
const Joi = require("@hapi/joi");

const input = [{
  "url": "test.com",
  "username": "Rishabh",
  "apiKeys": "test",
  "jobName": "testJob"
}, {
  "url": "test2.com",
  "username": "Rishabh2",
  "apiKeys": "test",
  "jobName": "testJob"
}, {
  "url": "test2.com",
  "username": "Rishabh2",
  "apiKeys": "test",
  "jobName": "testJob"
}];

const schema = Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
  "url": Joi.string().required(),
  "username": Joi.string().required(),
  "apiKeys": Joi.string().required(),
  "jobName": Joi.string().required()
})).unique();

console.log(schema.validate(input));
```

The key here is `unique();` and it works on n number of fields. No manual checks.

The response will tell you about if there was some duplicate or not. In this particular case `error` will contain

```
"value" position 2 contains a duplicate value
```

else the error will be null.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for a solution. Although here I am trying not to use any packages, I can use the schema validation package elsewhere.