# JavaScript how to map through two different arrays of objects and return one array conditionally

Tags: javascript

hello I need help creating the newProducts  in the following example array dynamically without knowing what's in the other two arrays
https://jsfiddle.net/od4267fv/
more explanation:

I would like to check

```
products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'product 1' ,
    liked:  false
  },
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'product 2' ,
    liked:  false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'product 3' ,
    liked:  false
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'product 4' ,
    liked:  false
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'product 5' ,
    liked:  false
  },

]
likedProducts = [
   {
    id: 1,
    name: 'product 1' ,
    liked:  true
  },
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'product 2' ,
    liked:  true
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'product 3' ,
    liked:  true
  },

]
if proucts[product].id === likedProducts[product].id
newProducts.push(likedProducts[product])
else
newProducts.push(proucts[product])
```

please recommend suitable ways to do it

Comment: answered a thousand times, you need an iterator that checks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587061/how-to-determine-if-object-is-in-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following using [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex),

```js
products = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'product 1' ,
    liked:  false
  },
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'product 2' ,
    liked:  false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'product 3' ,
    liked:  false
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'product 4' ,
    liked:  false
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'product 5' ,
    liked:  false
  },

]
likedProducts = [
   {
    id: 1,
    name: 'product 1' ,
    liked:  true
  },
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'product 2' ,
    liked:  true
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'product 3' ,
    liked:  true
  },

]

newProducts = products.map(item => {
  let index = likedProducts.findIndex(likedProduct => likedProduct.id === item.id);
  if(index > -1) {
    return likedProducts[index];
  }
  return item;
})

console.log(newProducts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const allProducts = products.filter(n => likedProducts.find(n2 => n.id == n2.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to iterate over 2 array and update value upon some certain condition.

```js
const updatedProduct = proucts.map((row, indexOfRows) => {
        for (let index = 0; index < likedProducts.length; index++) {
          if (likedProducts[index].id === row.id) {
            return likedProducts[index];
          }
        }
        return row;
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a single iteration over each of the arrays. First index all products by their id, then iterate over the liked products and overwrite the indexed items. This way, it doesn't matter how many items each array has, nor do you need to do constant lookups into at least one of the arrays.

```js
const products = [{id: 1,name: 'product 1' ,liked:  false},{id: 2,name: 'product 2' ,liked:  false},{id: 3,name: 'product 3' ,liked:  false},{id: 4,name: 'product 4' ,liked:  false},{id: 5,name: 'product 5' ,liked:  false},];
const likedProducts = [{id: 1,name: 'product 1' ,liked:  true},{id: 2,name: 'product 2' ,liked:  true},{id: 3,name: 'product 3' ,liked:  true},];

const index = new Map();

//index all products
for (let item of products) {
  index.set(item.id, item);
}

//overwrite anything that is liked 
for (let likedItem of likedProducts) {
  if (index.has(likedItem.id)) {
    index.set(likedItem.id, likedItem);
  }
}

//construct a new array from the values
const result = Array.from(index.values());

console.log(result);
```