# Video Poker How to make the combinations?

Tags: javascript, html, poker

I have been stuck on this for quite a while. So I thought I'd look it up. But with hours of searching I have come to ask on stack overflow as I am completely stumped.

Basically I am making a Web implementation of Jacks or Better: Video Poker. For some reason I keep getting my kings queen jacks and tens are recognized as the same value. And my full house keeps on being awarded. If my explanation isn't great then go to [here](https://www.veloceinternational.com/tips/video-poker-card-combinations/) or [here](https://www.casinoreports.ca/video-poker/rules/) to find out about the combinations.

If I need to send more code like the style tag I can do so, but I think this is all that is necessary. Any help is appreciated even ways to shorten down my code!

```
    <div id="canvas">
        <form method="post" id="play">
            <button>Play</button>
            <input id="played" type="hidden" name="postType" value="play">
        </form>
        <div id="selected"></div>
        <div id="winScreen">TYPE OF WIN!</div>
        <div id="draw" onclick="draw()">DRAW</div>
        <form action="/games/poker" method="post">
            <button id="reload" type="submit">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-arrow-clockwise" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8 3a5 5 0 1 0 4.546 2.914.5.5 0 0 1 .908-.417A6 6 0 1 1 8 2v1z"></path>
                  <path d="M8 4.466V.534a.25.25 0 0 1 .41-.192l2.36 1.966c.12.1.12.284 0 .384L8.41 4.658A.25.25 0 0 1 8 4.466z"></path>
                </svg>
              </button>
              <input id="woned" type="hidden" name="postType" value="won">
              <input id="who" type="hidden" name="won" value="None">
        </form>
        <div id="table"></div>

                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="border-color:orange; border-width:2.5px;">
                            <th>HAND</th>
                            <th>WIN</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ROYAL FLUSH</td>
                            <td>$250</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Straight Flush</td>
                            <td>$100</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Four of a Kind</td>
                            <td>$75</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Full house </td>
                            <td>$50</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Flush</td>
                            <td>$25</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Straight</td>
                            <td>$10</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Three of a Kind</td>
                            <td>$5</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Two of a Kind</td>
                            <td>$2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Jacks or Better</td>
                            <td>$1</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
        <div class="row stats">
            <div class="col">
                CASH: {{cash}}
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                BET: {{bet}}
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                WON: {{won}}
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
</div>


<script>
    let postType = "{{postType}}";
    var deck = [];
    let nummies = [];
    let numOfCards = 0;
    let cardsSel = [];
    function getCard(){
        let symbol = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1;
        let type = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1;
        if (symbol == 1){
            symbol = "D";
        }
        else if (symbol == 2){
            symbol = "S";
        }
        else if (symbol == 3){
            symbol = "H";
        }
        else if (symbol == 4){
            symbol = "C";
        }

        if (type == 1){
            type = "A";
        }
        else if (type == 10){
            type="T";
        }
        else if (type == 11){
            type="J";
        }
        else if (type == 12){
            type="Q";
        }
        else if (type == 13){
            type="K";
        }
        let item = {type:"", symbol:""};
        item.type = type;
        item.symbol = symbol;
        return item;
    }
    function makeCard(){
        let card = getCard();
        card = card.type + card.symbol + ".png";
        while (containsObject(card, deck)){
            card = getCard();
            card = card.type + card.symbol + ".png";
        }
        deck.push(card);
        return card;
    }
    if (postType == "play"){
        document.querySelector("#play").style.visibility = "hidden";
        let images = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            let card = makeCard();
            images.push('<button id="noButton" onclick="selected(' + '\'' + card + '\'' + ', ' + i + ')"><img class="cards" src="' + '/static/deck/' + card + '"></button>');
        }
        document.querySelector("#table").innerHTML = images.join(" ");
    }
    function draw(){
        let images = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 5 - numOfCards; i++){
            let card = makeCard();
            images.push('<button id="noButton"><img class="cards" src="' + '/static/deck/' + card + '"></button>');
            cardsSel.push(card.slice(0, 2));
        }
        document.querySelector("#draw").style.visibility = "hidden";
        document.querySelector("#reload").style.visibility = "visible";
        images.push(document.querySelector("#selected").innerHTML);
        document.querySelector("#selected").innerHTML = "";
        document.querySelector("#table").innerHTML = images.join(" ");

        // WIN COMBINATIONS

        // ROYAL FLUSH
        if (containsObject("AH", cardsSel) && containsObject("KH", cardsSel) && containsObject("QH", cardsSel) && containsObject("JH", cardsSel) && containsObject("TH", cardsSel)){
            winScreen("ROYAL FLUSH!");
        }
        else if (containsObject("AD", cardsSel) && containsObject("KD", cardsSel) && containsObject("QD", cardsSel) && containsObject("JD", cardsSel) && containsObject("TD", cardsSel)){
            winScreen("ROYAL FLUSH!");
        }
        else if (containsObject("AS", cardsSel) && containsObject("KS", cardsSel) && containsObject("QS", cardsSel) && containsObject("JS", cardsSel) && containsObject("TS", cardsSel)){
            winScreen("ROYAL FLUSH!");
        }
        else if (containsObject("AC", cardsSel) && containsObject("KC", cardsSel) && containsObject("QC", cardsSel) && containsObject("JC", cardsSel) && containsObject("TC", cardsSel)){
            winScreen("ROYAL FLUSH!");
        }
        let numberList = [];
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            let num = cardsSel[i][0];
            if (num == "A"){
                num = 1;
            }
            else if (num == "K"){
                num = 11;
            }
            else if (num == "Q"){
                num = 12;
            }
            else if (num == "J"){
                num = 13;
            }
            else if (num == "T"){
                num = 10;
            }
            else{
                num = parseInt(num);
            }
            numberList += num
        }
        // STRAIGHT FLUSH
        let hPossible = 0;
        let dPossible = 0;
        let sPossible = 0;
        let cPossible = 0;
        let possible = false;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if (cardsSel[i].indexOf("H") > -1){
                hPossible += 1;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if (cardsSel[i].indexOf("D") > -1){
                dPossible += 1;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if (cardsSel[i].indexOf("S") > -1){
                sPossible += 1;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if (cardsSel[i].indexOf("C") > -1){
                cPossible += 1;
            }
        }

        if (hPossible == 5 || dPossible == 5 || sPossible == 5 || cPossible == 5){
            possible = true;
        }

        if (possible == true){
            let outcome = false;
            let sorted = numberList.sort();
            let count = 0;

            for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                if (sorted[i] + 1 == sorted[i+1]){
                    count += 1;
                }
            }
            if (count == 5){
                outcome = true;
            }

            if (outcome == true){
                winScreen("STRAIGHT FLUSH!");
            }
        }

        // Four of a Kind

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            let selected = numberList[i];
            if (countObjects(numberList, selected) == 4){
                winScreen("Four of a Kind!");
            }
        }

        // Full house
        possible = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            let selected = numberList[i];
            if (countObjects(numberList, selected) == 3){
                possible += 1;
            }
            if (countObjects(numberList, selected) == 2){
                possible += 1;
            }
        }
        if (possible == 2){
            winScreen("Full House!");
        }

        // Flush
        hPossible = 0;
        dPossible = 0;
        sPossible = 0;
        cPossible = 0;
        possible = false;
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if (cardsSel[i].indexOf("H") > -1){
                hPossible += 1;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if (cardsSel[i].indexOf("D") > -1){
                dPossible += 1;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if (cardsSel[i].indexOf("S") > -1){
                sPossible += 1;
            }
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if (cardsSel[i].indexOf("C") > -1){
                cPossible += 1;
            }
        }

        if (hPossible == 5 || dPossible == 5 || sPossible == 5 || cPossible == 5){
            possible = true;
        }

        if (possible == true){
            winScreen("Flush!");
        }

        // Straight
        possible = false;
        let sorted = numberList.sort();
        let count = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            if (sorted[i] + 1 == sorted[i+1]){
                count += 1;
            }
        }
        if (count == 5){
            possible = true;
        }

        if (possible == true){
            winScreen("STRAIGHT FLUSH!");
        }

        // WIN COMBINATIONS

    }
    function selected(card, num){
        if (containsObject(num, nummies) == false){
            nummies.push(num);
            document.querySelector("#selected").innerHTML += '<img class="cards" src="' + '/static/deck/' + card + '">';
            numOfCards += 1;
            cardsSel.push(card.slice(0, 2));
        }
    }
    function countObjects(list, object){
        var j = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            if (list[i] == object){
                j++;
            }
        }
        return j;
    }
    function winScreen(type){
        document.querySelector("#winScreen").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.querySelector("#winScreen").innerHTML = type;
    }


    // Borrowed Scripts

    //https://stackoverflow.com/a/4587130/14214193
    function containsObject(obj, list) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i] === obj) {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer to the question. Huge thanks to stann for pointing out the area of problem. I fixed it by using two for loops instead of one as if there is 3 of the same card then possible will = 3 after the first one and after the second for loop it would equal 5.

```
    // Full house
    possible = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        let selected = numberList[i];
        if (countObjects(numberList, selected) == 3){
            possible += 1;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        if (countObjects(numberList, selected) == 2){
                possible += 1;
        }
    }
    if (possible == 5){
        winScreen("Full House!");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I may be wrong, but you are first creating array:

```
let numberList = [];
```

and then instead of pushing into the array, you are incrementing numberList, so it's converted into string with added numbers. Screen below:

[image: consolelog incrementation]

Instead of

```
numberList += num
```

use

```
numberList.push(num)
```

so it adds number into the array, like in example below:

[image: example with array]

So now, your function countObjects will work properly. :)
I'm not sure if it resolves your problem, but I'm sure it will help in current development and problem solving.

//Edit: Added problem solve for Full House

```
// Full house
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      possible = 0;
      let selected = numberList[i];
      if (countObjects(numberList, selected) == 3){
        possible += 1;
      }
      if (countObjects(numberList, selected) == 2){
        possible += 1;
      }
    }
    if (possible == 2){
      winScreen("Full House!");
    }
```

Comment: No problem, let me know if that helped. If not, I'll try to debug your code some more. :)

Comment: I see it working much better and some of the incremental combinations are working now but things like four of a kind and full house are randomly popping in. I used to think it was because of the kings queens jacks having the same value but it does not seem like that.

Comment: I found another problem in your code, that will solve "Full house" popping in:
under //Full house comment, move possible = 0; inside the for. 

Reason:
'possible' set out of 'for' is counting +1 everytime if any of ifs inside is triggered. So if you set it inside for, it will count possible ONLY if BOTH of ifs are matching. Now it works like that: possible adds +1, because it found 2 same objects, then possible = 1, and iteration is run again, again it finds 2 same objects, so it adds to possible +1, now possible = 2, and it fullfills your last if - possible == 2.

I think it should help

Comment: o.o Oh sorry for the late reply I will try that immediately!

Comment: I see your point but that means it can never be achieved as possible is always set to 0 so that means that it should never reach 2. My conclusion is that I have approached this wrong.

Comment: Fixed it thanks for all the help I have updated my code so you can see the fixes. Again thanks so much!

Comment: No problem, glad that I could help somehow. :)