# check if array object does not contain a object

Tags: javascript

I just started to learn javascript today and i'm trying to check an array object to check if the array does NOT contain a object.

For an example i am trying to check if `data2` does not contain `data1`.

```js
let data1 = [{ x: 6232, y: 10536, type: "data4", dead: 0, uid: 3832864 }];

let data2 = [
  { x: 6352, y: 10656, type: "data1", dead: 0, uid: 3832861 },
  { x: 6322, y: 10546, type: "data2", dead: 0, uid: 3832862 },
  { x: 6542, y: 15356, type: "data3", dead: 0, uid: 3832863 }
];

let check = Object.entries(data2).find(([key, value]) => value.uid != data1[0].uid);
console.log(check); // Expected output to be fales.
```

If someone could help me or point me in the right direction i would really appreciate it.

Comment: Is there a unique property in your objects? This is often why objects have an `id`.

Comment: @LaytonGB I assume that is the `uid` property.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if object is in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587061/how-to-determine-if-object-is-in-array)

Comment: What would be the criteria to consider an item in `data1` equal to an item in `data2`? Should the both have the exact same key/value pairs? It suffices they have the same `uid`? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare (`===`) the result of `find` with `!undefined`.

**Edit:** You do not need to call `entries` on an array.

```js
const data1 = [{ x: 6232, y: 10536, type: "data4", dead: 0, uid: 3832864 }];

const data2 = [
  { x: 6352, y: 10656, type: "data1", dead: 0, uid: 3832861 },
  { x: 6322, y: 10546, type: "data2", dead: 0, uid: 3832862 },
  { x: 6542, y: 15356, type: "data3", dead: 0, uid: 3832863 }
];

const check = data2.find(value => value.uid === data1[0].uid) !== undefined;

console.log(check); // false
```

As others have noted, you can short-circuit with `some`. Here is an optimized version:

```js
/**
 * Detrmines if an object exists within an array of object
 * @param {Object[]} arr - An array of object to search
 * @param {Object} obj - An object to search for
 * @param {Function} fn - A pluck function used for comparing
 * @return {Boolean} Returns true if the item exists
 */
const contains = (arr, obj, fn) =>
  (res => arr.some(e => fn(e) === res)) // Compare 
  (fn(obj)); // Pre-calculate as `res`
  
const data1 = [{ x: 6232, y: 10536, type: "data4", dead: 0, uid: 3832864 }];

const data2 = [
  { x: 6352, y: 10656, type: "data1", dead: 0, uid: 3832861 },
  { x: 6322, y: 10546, type: "data2", dead: 0, uid: 3832862 },
  { x: 6542, y: 15356, type: "data3", dead: 0, uid: 3832863 }
];

const [obj] = data1; // Destructure first item

console.log(contains(data2, obj, ({ uid }) => uid)); // false

console.log(contains(data2, { uid: 3832862 }, ({ uid }) => uid)); // true
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you are tackling this problem is okay, and the other answer will help you fix it. But this is ideally supposed to be solved as an array. With `Object.entries()` you are getting the array objects and indices as  values & keys respectively. Then you iterate over them.

**You can notice you are not even using the key variable.**

No need to do all this since you **already have an array**.

You can use `.some()`, which returns true/false based on a condition which even one of the array item fulfills. Exactly what you need.

```js
let data1 = [{ x: 6232, y: 10536, type: "data4", dead: 0, uid: 3832864 }];

let data2 = [
  { x: 6352, y: 10656, type: "data1", dead: 0, uid: 3832861 },
  { x: 6322, y: 10546, type: "data2", dead: 0, uid: 3832862 },
  { x: 6542, y: 15356, type: "data3", dead: 0, uid: 3832863 }
];

let check = data2.some(x => x.uid === data1[0].uid);
console.log(check); // Expected output to be fales.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few syntax errors in your code above. `data2` is an array of objects so you don't need to do Object.entries() to get the elements of the array. I would use Array.some() method here so that it returns a boolean value instead of the actual data element if you are hoping to have a true or false value logged. the Array.some() method just returns once one case is true and we don't have to go through all the entries in the array of object if we already found a match.

```
let data1 = [{ x: 6232, y: 10536, type: "data4", dead: 0, uid: 3832864 }];

let data2 = [
  { x: 6352, y: 10656, type: "data1", dead: 0, uid: 3832861 },
  { x: 6322, y: 10546, type: "data2", dead: 0, uid: 3832862 },
  { x: 6542, y: 15356, type: "data3", dead: 0, uid: 3832863 },
  { x: 6232, y: 10536, type: "data4", dead: 0, uid: 3832864 }
];

let check = data2.some(entry => entry.uid == data1[0].uid);
console.log(check); // Expected output to be true.
```

If you didn't have a unique id for each entry then a quick and dirty way to do this would be to stringify both objects and then compare the strings. This has its limitations because the order of the fields in your object must be the same.

```
var object = { 'a': 1, 'b':2};
var other = { 'a': 1, 'b':2 };
 
console.log(JSON.stringify(object) == JSON.stringify(other)); //this will print true
```

For deep object comparison, I like to use the isequal method from [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual)

```js
var object = { 'a': 1, 'b':2};
var other = { 'b':2, 'a': 1 };
 
console.log(JSON.stringify(object) == JSON.stringify(other)); //this will print false
console.log(_.isEqual(object, other)); //this will print true
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `Object.entries()` (the exact approach you've taken with minimum changes):

```js
let data1 = [{ x: 6232, y: 10536, type: "data4", dead: 0, uid: 3832864 }];

let data2 = [
  { x: 6352, y: 10656, type: "data1", dead: 0, uid: 3832861 },
  { x: 6322, y: 10546, type: "data2", dead: 0, uid: 3832862 },
  { x: 6542, y: 15356, type: "data3", dead: 0, uid: 3832863 }
];

let check;
Object.entries(data2).find(([key, value]) => check = value.uid === data1[0].uid);
console.log(check); //false
```